# Odoo11 - How i get opening stock datewise?

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo-10, odoo-11

I would like to get opening stock on particular date. to print in PDF report in odoo 11.
 Thanks,
Anand.

Comment: this is unclear what you want and what u tried????

Comment: can you describe your question in brief ?